# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac {a - x^2 \ln {\left|1-\frac {a}{x^2}\right|}}{b\ln {\left|1-\frac {a}{x^2}\right|}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate:$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac {a - x^2 \ln {\left|1-\frac {a}{x^2}\right|}}{b\ln {\left|1-\frac {a}{x^2}\right|}}}$$

I tried solving this using L'Hôpital's rule, and the limit appears to be unbounded. However, when graphed using a calculator (with random values of $a$ and $b$), it appears to converge to a definite value. I wanted to confirm if this limit exists.

Comment: For applying L'Hoptal's rule, the limit must be in $\frac{0}0$ form. You can't apply  it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerator tends to $2a$ (which is non-zero otherwise the expression has no sense), and the denominator tends to $0$, so the limit is not finite.